# Unable to invoke instantiateitems method in viewpager pageadapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter, imageswitcher

I am unable to invoke the instantiateitem method while trying to make an image slider in Android activity. There aren't any errors showing but the images aren't visible, here is the adapter code:

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{

    ImageView imageView;

    private int[] image_resources={R.drawable.bus,R.drawable.cp,R.drawable.ty};
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        Log.d("**************","**************5");
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        Log.d("**************","**************7");
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,null);
         imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        ViewPager vp=(ViewPager)container;
        vp.addView(view,0);
        //container.addView(view);
        Log.d("**************","**************8");
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        ViewPager vp =(ViewPager)container;
        View view=(View)object;
        vp.removeView(view);
        //container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning 0 in getCount(). Return length of the number of images you want to show like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}
```